# How to self-update a Java Desktop Application?

Tags: java, javafx, open-source, self-updating

I built a java desktop application with Java8 and JavaFX. And everything works fine.

But now I have a new challenge! I googled a lot about how to self-update a java desktop app, but all the results I found were old.

Is there an Open Source library that can manage self-updates for java applications like https://github.com/Squirrel?

If not, what is the best way to build something that will allow my desktop app to self update?

Thank you.

Comment: There is bound to be a library, but for my own apps I run them through my own launcher that checks a version number with my server, then if different it retrieves a list of files/classes that are newer than the client version and download and updates before launching the my app. If its basic then you can do it all through HTTP GET requests (although there are better methods).

Answer (score 0):

There is a lib called [UpdateFX](https://github.com/bitgamma/updatefx) which handles the update process for you. Only drawback is that it only works with single jar apps so if you are using extra libs you have to extend it.